# Enable cross site functionality for a subset of my application

Tags: apache-2.4, cookies

A part of the web application I'm working on is integrated with another web application that I do not have control over.
This integration has stopped working with the recent enforcement of the SameSite cookie attribute. For this integration to start working again, my **JSESSIONID** cookie needs to have the *SameSite=None* attribute set, as well as *Secure* (for obvious reasons).

My team and I have decided to let the Apache Server handle this case, which works part of the time.

As a side note, we have also decided to set *SameSite=Strict* for all cookies, excluding those who should be set to *SameSite=None*.

This is my **cookies.conf**, included in my **apache2.conf** (names replaced with place holders):

```
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;Secure;SameSite=Strict;

<If "%{THE_REQUEST} =~ m#.*\/application-instance\/subset-of-app.*#">
    Header edit Set-Cookie (JSESSIONID.*) $1;Secure;SameSite=None; 
</If>
```

The first Header directive line works perfectly, as well as the line inside the If-statement, would it be outside the If-statement. What does not work is the expression.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it possible to do this or am I misunderstanding something? Hopefully there's enough information, and that I'm on the right page..

**EDIT:**

I probably should have mentioned that I can successfully set the cookie to "SameSite=None" for whole instances of the application, like so:

```
<If "%{THE_REQUEST} =~ m#.*\/application-instance.*#">
    Header edit Set-Cookie (JSESSIONID.*) $1;Secure;SameSite=None; 
</If>
```

Also, I know my regex for the subset of the app works since these lines actually create a new JSESSIONID-cookie with the same name and value, but with SameSite=None, only available for the specified path:

```
<If "%{THE_REQUEST} =~ m#.*\/application-instance\/subset-of-app.*#">
    SetEnvIf Cookie "(^|;\ *)JSESSIONID=([^;\ ]+)" JSESSIONID_VALUE=$2
    Header always set Set-Cookie JSESSIONID=%{JSESSIONID_VALUE}e;Secure;SameSite=None;Path=/application-instance/subset-of-app.page;
</If>
```

I'm not very confident in that this is the correct way to solve this problem, as having two JSESSIONID-cookies might give inconsistent results in the third party app..

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as though at /application-instance/subset-of-app, both rules should be firing, so you're setting the cookie:

```
JSESSIONID=...;Secure;SameSite=Strict;Secure;SameSite=None;
```

Since SameSite is being set twice to different values, could that be confusing clients? So maybe instead you want:

```
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;Secure;SameSite=Strict;
<If "%{THE_REQUEST} =~ m#.*\/application-instance\/subset-of-app.*#">
    Header edit Set-Cookie (JSESSIONID.*);SameSite=Strict; $1;SameSite=None; 
</If>
```

You can examine the `Set-Cookie` response header values by using `curl -sv` or your browser's development tools, which may help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This did not work for me unfortunately, though it sure looks like this would affect my results. Is there a way to view all the attributes set to the cookie?

Comment: Added to the answer. Good luck.